# Navbar dosen't open

Tags: html

Hi I am trying to make a navbar but my dropdown menu dosen't work. Can someone help me with this? Also I want to ask how can I put multiple colors in a navbar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tesla</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/navbar.html">Tesla</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
 Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>



</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about your current solution doesn't work?

Comment: Please spend some time researching before asking a question, this is a very common use and plenty of examples on the web.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have Javascript in place that will decide what happens when the user clicks on the dropdown icon.

I would recommend having a look at this example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_mobile_navbar

Comment: Please, avoid pasting links to W3Schools - It's the main reason people end up here on stackoverflow still in 2021. (Unrelated - but related to your latest question you deleted: https://jsbin.com/zayijucuji/edit?html,css,js,console,output)